# i have problems sending email

Tags: string, email, smtp

I try to send an Email where the settings are coming from a textfile.
i am stuck at the PORT section of the smtp part. it seems i can not use the digit "26" of my textfile (as it is an int?)
Thank you (yes i am a beginner in C#)

textfile entries:

```
mymail@myserver.com
myemail@myprovider.com
passwort123
Randy
myemailsmtpprovider.com
false
26
```

and here is what i try:

```
private void SendEmail(string file)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(@"settings.txt");
                var fromAddress = new MailAddress(content[0], content[3]);
                var toAddress = new MailAddress(content[0], content[3]);
                string fromPassword = content[2].ToString();
                const string subject = "Alarm Snapshot";
                const string body = "Motion detected";

                var attachmentFilename = file;
                var attachment = new Attachment(attachmentFilename,  MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                if (attachmentFilename != null)
                {
                    ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;
                    disposition.CreationDate = File.GetCreationTime(attachmentFilename);
                    disposition.ModificationDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(attachmentFilename);
                    disposition.ReadDate = File.GetLastAccessTime(attachmentFilename);
                    disposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(attachmentFilename);
                    disposition.Size = new FileInfo(attachmentFilename).Length;
                    disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;
                }
                    var smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    
                    Host = content[4],
                    Port =26, 
                    // here is the proble. i want to use the entriy content[6] 
                    // from the textfile instead of write 26 directly
                    
                    EnableSsl = false,
                    // same with Ssl, i can not use the entry from the textfile

                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
                };
                using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                {
                    Subject = subject,
                    Body = body
                })
                {
                    message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    smtp.Send(message);
                    InvokeGuiThread(() => label_Email.Text = @"Sending successful");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Error: " + exception.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: *"it seems i can not use the digit "26" of my textfile"* - Why not?  What's the actual problem or error that you are observing?  When you step through the code in a debugger, what specifically fails?

Comment: it says: the type "String" can not converted to "int"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175228/string-to-number)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

these two Lines had to be (parsed) converted:

```
Port = content[6],
EnableSsl = content[5],
```

into

```
Port = int.Parse(content[6]),
EnableSsl = bool.Parse(content[5]),
```